# Docker deployment to remote server fails

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, yarnpkg

I try to deploy docker to a remote server with docker context, but it keeps failing with this error on a RUN yarn build stage (all the previous steps are running ok):

```
failed to receive status: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: command [ssh -l root -- <remote-server-ip> docker system dial-stdio] has exited with exit status 255, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=
```

I have a single container with Next.js project in it and I deploy it with this command: `docker-compose --context remote up -d`
My host is on MacOS and the remote host is Ubuntu with docker 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.2.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

If anyone countered such an issue I would be grateful to get any help. What might be the thing causing error?

**UPDATE**

When I run `ssh -l root -- <remote server ip> docker version` it gives me this output:

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.1
 Git commit:        20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
 Built:             Thu Apr 27 05:56:19 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.1
  Git commit:       20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
  Built:            Thu Apr 27 05:37:01 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.12-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

Additionally, here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  agregator:
    build: .
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: ["yarn", "start"]
```

Comment: What happens if you run `ssh -l root -- <remote server ip> docker version`?

Comment: @BMitch as the output is long I added it to the question.